# Skip whitespacing from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I skip whitespacing from being counted and colored in my little script ?
It is counted in my script and colored and I have no clues how to skip it, not to effect characters. So the point is to colour every 2nd letter. Any tips ?

I know how I'd do it with jQuery but I am practising JavaScript instead.

[JS Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dvLden/u9BUK/)

```
var div = document.createElement('div'),
    first = 'First JavaScript string.',
    second = 'This is second text.',
    combine = first + ' ' + second,
    colored = '';

div.id = 'sort-text';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);

for (i = 0; i < combine.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 1) {
        colored += '<span style="color: #d10;">' + combine[i] + '</span>';
    } else {
        colored += combine[i];
    }
}

div.innerHTML = colored;
```

Comment: well you could just wrap the body of the for loop in an `if (combine[i] !== " ")`, right? Or am I missing something... That won't catch newlines of course, but you can also check for `/n` (I think there maybe some weird OS specific newline cases though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). It's much cleaner than a for-loop for this problem.

For example:

```
var curr = -1;
colored = combine.split("").map(function(x) {
    if (x === " ") return x; // Ignore space
    curr++; // Otherwise, increment
    if (curr % 2 === 1)
      return '<span style="color: #d10;">' + x + '</span>';
    return x;
}).join("");
```

You can easily extend this to include other punctuation as well as patterns.

For example, if we want to ignore both periods and spaces, we can do this:

```
var curr = -1;
var ignore = ". "; // Ignore space and period
colored = combine.split("").map(function(x) {
    if (ignore.indexOf(x) >= 0) return x;
    curr++;
    if (curr % 2 === 1)
      return '<span style="color: #d10;">' + x + '</span>';
    return x;
}).join("");
```

<kbd>[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/u9BUK/3/)</kbd>

Comment: Very good approach... I haven't heard of .map() tho, so I need to read about it first. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var space_offset = 0;
for (i = 0; i < combine.length; i++) {
    if ( combine[i] == ' ' ) {
        space_offset++;
        colored += combine[i];
    } else if ( ( i + space_offset ) % 2 == 1) {
        colored += '<span style="color: #d10;">' + combine[i] + '</span>';
    } else {
        colored += combine[i];
    }
}
```

I added an offset variable that would maintain the idea that every other letter ignoring spaces should be coloured.

Answer (score 2):

You can white list things you don't want to count, like spaces, and use a separate variable rather than relying on the character index.

```
var useRed = false;

for (i = 0; i < combine.length; i++) {
    if (combine[i] != ' ') {
        if (useRed) {
            colored += '<span style="color: #d10;">' + combine[i] + '</span>';
            useRed = false;
        } else {
            colored += combine[i];
            useRed = true
        }
    }
    else {
        colored += combine[i];
    }
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9BUK/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a task for `continue`:

```
var i, len, str, bol, curr_char, new_str;

str = "hello wolrd this is a test.";
new_str = "";
bol = false;

for(i=0, len=str.length; i<len; i++){
    curr_char = str.charAt(i);

    if(curr_char===" "){
        new_str += curr_char;
        continue;
    }

    if(bol){
        new_str += "<span style='color: #d10;'>" + curr_char + "</span>";
    }else{
        new_str += curr_char;
    }

    bol = !bol;
}

console.log(new_str);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is other option:

```
var i, len, old_str, new_str, color_toggler, current_char, is_space;

old_str = "hello world this is a test.";
new_str = "";
color_toggler = true;

for(i=0, len=old_str.length; i<len; i++){
    current_char = old_str.charAt(i);
    is_space = (current_char===" ");

    if(!is_space){
        color_toggler = !color_toggler;
    }

    if(color_toggler || is_space){
        new_str += current_char;
    }else{
        new_str += "<span style='color: #d10;'>" + current_char + "</span>";
    }
}

console.log(new_str);
```

Comment: Nice I like this one... No particular reason, it's just simple to understand. Thanks for two answers ajax!